# SharePoint 2013 AAM Issue

Tags: iis, alternate-access-mapping

My SharePoint 2013 instance was originally deployed into production as local intranet access only (i.e. http:SPABC01:12351) and later when I finished I configured the internet zone (i.e. http://sharepoint.company.com).

Once I made the switch, a few issues popped up.

1. First issue, none of the OOB Workflows will run. They all fail at
   start.
2. Second issue, all notification being sent from SharePoint
   contain URLs for the default zone and not the Internet zone (I’m the
   only one that has access to the default zone).
3. Last issue, When I tried to change the default zone public URL to the internet zone URL, I get a 404 when trying to access. I have even tried flipping
   the two zone and get the same result.

I am not an IIS or DNS expert so I feel there must be something I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, All the alerts will be sent using the Default Zone Url. So whatevery your URL in default zone, it will be used for all communication.

Couple of things to check.

- Your DNS, configured to WFE of the SharePoint(SPABC01, i think this is ur wfe).
- Make sure you have the IIS bindings for the DNS.
- You should add another internal URL in default zone and put the server name and port number in it.